# An identity about Jacobson Radical $\theta(J(R))=J(S)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am reading the proof of [Corollary 13.2](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&lpg=PA159&pg=PA179#v=onepage&q&f=false) from Isaacs' Algebra.

Okay, I get the intuitive idea but have couple of disconnections:
1-In the first paragraph it says:

> Every simple right $S$-module can be seen as an $R$-module, and as
>   such, it is simple

I am not sure that preserving of being simple is obvious, and i cant see it.
2-In the second paragraph it says:

> Since every simple $R$-module is annihilated by $J(R)\supseteq \ker(\theta)$, each can be viewed as an $S$-module and so is
>   annihilated by $J(S)$

I can see why every simple $R$-module can be viewed as $S$-module, but i cant put $\ker(\theta )$ in the business.
Would please help me to understand this proof? Thanks.

Comment: your link doesn't work

Comment: are you sure? it works when i click. even in different browsers.

Comment: I have updated the link.

Comment: Link doesn't work for me either, but luckily I have the reference in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, it sound like you haven't looked at the module actions closely enough.

If $A$ is a simple left $S$ module, we view it as an $R$ module with the action $ar:=a\theta(r)$. (Later I'll be recycling $A$ for use as an $R$ module.)

> *I am not sure that preserving of being simple is obvious*

Perhaps this alternative characterization of simplicity is what you need. Saying $A_S$ is simple is equivalent to saying that $S$ acts transitively on its nonzero elements. (That is, if $a,b\in A\setminus\{0\}$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $as=b$.)  From the above module action, it's easy to see that $R$ acts transitively if $S$ does.

> *but i can't put ker(θ) in the business.*

In this half, we're trying to take an $R$ module and make an $S$ module out of it using the mapping $\theta$. An optimist might expect that reversing the definition that we did before would work, that is, for $s=\theta(r)$, $as:=ar$. The problem is that *this isn't well-defined unless $\ker(\theta)\subseteq ann(A)$*. When this is satisfied, then the optimistic definition works. (I invite you to examine the details to prove well-definedness.)

In that half of the problem, the assumption that $A_R$ is simple puts $J(R)$ into the annihilator of $A$, but by the first part we have that $\ker(\theta)\subseteq J(R)$. That proves $\ker(\theta)\subseteq ann(A)$, allowing us to use the desired module action.

Comment: First of all it's a very detailed answer, thank you for your time. I mean it. I didnt know about acting transitively concept. That made things more clear. For the second part, I have checked the well definedness of group action, and i see that kernel being inside annihilator makes the action well def'd.